# How to work out stacked probabilities

Tags: probability, percentages

This is basically a gaming question :)

On an action, an ability can be triggered 50% of the time. This can be upgraded one of two ways.

This first is simple, it can be upgraded to 65%

The other is less simple, it can be upgraded so that 35% of the time, the action will trigger again, with both actions having a 50% chance that the ability could trigger.

So Action -> 50% Ability trigger. Then 35% chance that the action triggers again, again with a 50% chance that the ability triggers again.

Triggers always have a 15% chance they fail.

If I care about the ability triggers, which is better?

Comment: Can ability trigger happen more than once, in the second situation?

Comment: @T_M No, an ability can only be triggered one per action.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).